# Searching for Sci-fi novel from the 1980's

Tags: story-identification, novel, armor

I am trying to find a sci-fi novel I read briefly when I was young and waiting in line at a Goodwill. The main subject was about a soldier in power armor fighting a race of lizard like aliens and in the first chapter a soldier near him died after a lizard alien got inside his power armor and ate him. I do not remember the title or author.

I remember the cover seemed to be a desert planet and the soldier in his white or grey power armor walking in a direction and looking slightly behind him. I remember the power armor gave him incredible strength. Any tips are appreciated.

I thought it was Starship Troopers, but I remember the aliens being lizard like or reptilian. The details are vague because this was around 12 years ago, but I distinctly remember that on the power armor, it wasn't a helmet with a visor, but a face mask instead on the helmet. The face mask looked almost like a low poly character design. Lots of angles.

It is not Armor by John Steakley.

Comment: Off to a good start, but the more details the better, can I suggest you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can [edit] in any more details?

Comment: Starship Troopers perhaps?

Comment: I thought it was Starship Troopers, but I remember the aliens being lizard like or reptilian. The details are vague because this was around 12 years ago, but I distinctly remember that on the power armor, it wasn't a helmet with a visor, but a face mask instead on the helmet. The face mask looked almost like a low poly character design. Lots of angles.

Comment: Possibly Halderman's [The Forever War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Forever_War)?

Comment: I wonder if it was a Warhammer novel. Power armour features in those novels.

Comment: Not Forever War sadly. I'm pretty sure it was kind of obscure, and more like the dime a dozen science fiction stories that were pumped out in the 70's and 80's.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81867/need-help-finding-a-specific-scifi-trilogy-2000-2004 (about the series)

Answer (score 10):

Possibly Solar Kill by Charles Ingrid (#1 of 6 of the Sand Wars series)

[image: Solar Kill]

In the first chapter the Protagonist recalls a rumor

> And there were too many stories about altered suits … suits that swallowed a man up and spawned instead some kind of lizard-beastman who was a fighting automaton, a berserker. Rumor had it the Milots were putting eggs into the suits, and the heat and sweat of the suit wearer hatched those eggs and then the parasitic creature devoured its host and burst forth—

Later in the first chapter he does describe a creature bursting out of a suit of a soldier who died in his suit (ran out of power? or supplies?)

> And he sees a suit burst open, days after its wearer expired with a horrendous scream, and the armor halted like a useless statue in the pit. He sees the seams pop and an incredible beast plow out, and charge the rim of the pit, taking fully a hundred armed Thrakians with it, even as it bellows. He knows he is dreaming that he has seen a berserker, and tries to ignore the shell-like empty suit left behind in shards, with the crest of Ivanhoe settling into the sand.

Comment: Holy cow. That's it! Thank you so much! I've been looking for this for 12 years. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like Bill the Galactic Hero by Harry Harrison.  Farm boy Bill is tricked into joining up and ends fighting the lizard like Chingers.

This is a very different and satirical take on the subject to the one Heinlein took in Starship Troopers, it's been described as 'a dramatic summary of all the criticism of Starship Troopers'.

Comment: One of the details that night stick with you is that, by the end of the first book, battlefield medicine has given Bill two right arms and an oversized chicken foot.

Comment: Maybe https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1273022984l/2433462.jpg for the "mask".

Comment: As funny as that sounds, the book had a serious tone. Like horrors of war and very descriptive. Going to have to read your suggestion now though.

Comment: Bil (one 'l'; 2 'l's are for officers only) never wears the powered armor in that book - it only shows up for one very short scene where it quickly sinks into a swamp.